# How do I allow duplicates in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to compare column A in sheet2 to column A in sheet1 and when there's a match, copy the row from sheet1 to sheet3 with the same order. And if there is a repetition, it should be included too. I also need it to show the mismatching values empty. I did this macro but I can not allow the duplicates to be included.

```
Sub compareAndCopy()
    Dim lastRowE As Long
    Dim lastRowF As Long
    Dim lastRowM As Long
    Dim foundTrue As Boolean

    ' stop screen from updating to speed things up
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    lastRowE = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Sheets("Sheet2").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastRowF = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastRowM = Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(Sheets("Sheet3").Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To lastRowE
        foundTrue = False
        For j = 1 To lastRowF
            If Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 1).Value Then
                lastRowM = lastRowM + 1
                Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy Destination:= _
                    Sheets("Sheet3").Rows(lastRowM)
                foundTrue = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j

        'If Not foundTrue Then
        '   MsgBox ("didn't find string: " & Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 2).value)
        'End If
    Next i

    ' allow screen updating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Remove the `Exit For` line?

Comment: it didn't work. it gave results without repetitions.

Comment: You are only increasing lastrowM if the condition is true.  You can move that line out of the If..then statement and it will show empty when not true.

Comment: I tried it but i didn't work

Comment: You've got `Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy` but it should be `j` not `i`. That, plus removing `Exit For` is definitely the answer. Tested and working.

Answer (score 1):

### Group Data

- Loops through probably unique values in column `A` of `Sheet2`.
- For each cell value, it uses the `Find` and `FindNext` methods to find all the matching cells in column `A` of `Sheet1`.
- Then it writes each of the cell values to a key, and using `Union`, combines each matching cell to a range object in the corresponding item.
- Then it loops through the dictionary and copies the entire rows of each item (range) to `Sheet3`.
- Finally, it clears the newly added values in column `A` of `Sheet3`.
- The result in `Sheet3` is data from `Sheet1` grouped by the values in column `A` of `Sheet2`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CompareAndCopy()
    
    Const eName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const eCol As String = "A"
    Const efRow As Long = 1 ' don't you have headers?
    
    Const fName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const fCol As String = "A"
    Const ffRow As Long = 1 ' don't you have headers?
    
    Const mName As String = "Sheet3"
    Const mCol As String = "B" ' "A" is empty!
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim ews As Worksheet: Set ews = wb.Worksheets(eName)
    Dim elRow As Long: elRow = ews.Cells(ews.Rows.Count, eCol).End(xlUp).Row
    If elRow < efRow Then Exit Sub ' no data
    Dim erg As Range: Set erg = ews.Cells(efRow, eCol).Resize(elRow - efRow + 1)
    'Debug.Print erg.Address
    
    Dim fws As Worksheet: Set fws = wb.Worksheets(fName)
    Dim flRow As Long: flRow = fws.Cells(fws.Rows.Count, fCol).End(xlUp).Row
    If flRow < ffRow Then Exit Sub ' no data
    Dim frg As Range:
    Set frg = fws.Cells(ffRow, fCol).Resize(flRow - ffRow + 1)
    'Debug.Print frg.Address
    
    Dim mws As Worksheet: Set mws = wb.Worksheets(mName)
    Dim mifCell As Range
    Set mifCell = mws.Cells(mws.Rows.Count, mCol).End(xlUp).Offset(1) _
        .EntireRow.Columns("A") ' entire rows
    Dim mfCell As Range: Set mfCell = mifCell
    'Debug.Print mfCell.Address
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim frCount As Long: frCount = frg.Rows.Count
    
    Dim eCell As Range
    Dim eValue As Variant
    Dim fCell As Range
    Dim FirstAddress As String
    
    For Each eCell In erg.Cells
        eValue = eCell.Value
        Set fCell = frg.Find(eValue, frg.Cells(frCount), xlFormulas, xlWhole)
        If Not fCell Is Nothing Then
             FirstAddress = fCell.Address
            Do
                If dict.Exists(eValue) Then
                    Set dict(eValue) = Union(dict(eValue), fCell)
                Else
                    Set dict(eValue) = fCell
                End If
                Set fCell = frg.FindNext(fCell)
            Loop Until fCell.Address = FirstAddress
        End If
    Next eCell
    
    If dict.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub  ' no data¸
    
    Dim rg As Range
    Dim Item As Variant
    Dim irCount As Long
    For Each Item In dict.Items
        irCount = Item.Cells.Count
        'Debug.Print Item.Address, irCount
        Item.EntireRow.Copy mfCell.EntireRow
        Set mfCell = mfCell.Offset(irCount)
    Next Item
    
    mifCell.Resize(mfCell.Row - mifCell.Row).ClearContents ' or .Clear
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Data grouped.", vbInformation

End Sub
```